What's the difference between [terminology] and [technical]? Burninate [technical]?
The usage guidance for the terminology tag reads:

For questions about technical or specialized words in fields like grammar, IT, politics, sports, etc.

Which is very much appropriate. The formal definition of "terminology" is:

the body of terms used with a particular technical application in a subject of study, profession, etc.

We also have the technical tag, with no usage guidance and a grand total of 10 questions:

What is an “exoactive” Chinese character?. [terminology] seems appropriate
The origin of 勾 and 股 in The Pythagorean Theorem 勾股定理 more focused on [etymology], but [terminology] also seems appropriate
Glossary of Technical Terms relating to Knitting and Knitting Machines. English <>Chinese [vocabulary] seems appropriate. [terminology] too
translating a few words on this microprocessor block diagram this one should probably be closed. [translation] seems appropriate, and [terminology] a nice addition
Where can I find Chinese language soft subtitles for domestic television programs? this one also should probably be closed. the current tags seem a bit random, [technical] doesn't sound appropriate
What is “singleton set” in Chinese? [terminology] seems appropriate
How to say network but not internet this might be fine with [translation] only, but [terminology] might also work
Good resource to learn scientific Chinese [terminology] seems appropriate
Is this dictionary Chinese, Japanese or both? not sure how to tag this. [technical] seems unnecessary
Is there an authoritative list of most frequent to most infrequent pronunciations for individual Chinese characters? [technical] seems unnecessary

Given the small number of technical questions, I propose to retag, and burninate the tag.

I'm happy with all this.

@Becky李蓓 it's done! [technical] = zero results. I also wrote a first version of [terminology] tag wiki

Maybe [sport] is no longer needed?  (They can also be renamed [terminology].)
